# SQL Query Profit and Loss

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables in SQL Server: TblGroup and TblAmount

**TblGroup**

```
Grp_Id  Grp_Name            GrpType
------  --------------      -----------
1       Direct Incomes      Income
2       Indirect Incomes    Income
3       Misc. Expences      Expence
4       Other Incomes       Income
5       Purchases           Expence
6       Selling Expences    Expence
7       Sales               Income
```

**TblAmount**

```
Grp_Id  Amount          
------  -------
1       2000
2       1500
3       3000
4       5000
5       4000
6       1000
7       4500
```

This is the output that I need:

```
Income              Amount  Expence             Amount
-------------       -----   -------------       ----------
Direct Incomes      2000    Misc. Expences      3000
Indirect Incomes    1500    Purchases           4000
Other Incomes       5000    Selling Expences    1000
Sales               4500
```

This is my query, but not getting the right result:

```
declare @TblGroup as table (Grp_Id int, Grp_Name varchar(50), GrpType varchar(20))
insert into @TblGroup values    
     (1,'Direct Incomes','Income')
    ,(2,'Indirect Incomes','Income')
    ,(3,'Misc. Expences','Expence')
    ,(4,'Other Incomes','Income')
    ,(5,'Purchases','Expence')
    ,(6,'Selling Expences','Expence')
    ,(7,'Sales','Income')

declare @TblAmount as table(Grp_Id int,Amount int)
insert into @TblAmount values
     (1,2000)   
    ,(2,1500)   
    ,(3,3000)   
    ,(4,5000)   
    ,(5,4000)   
    ,(6,1000)   
    ,(7,4500)   

select * from (
    SELECT Grp_Name AS Income, Amount AS Amount
    FROM @TblGroup g
    LEFT JOIN @TblAmount a ON g.Grp_Id = a.Grp_Id
    WHERE GrpType = 'Income') as Income 
JOIN (
    SELECT Grp_Name AS Expence, Amount AS Amount
    FROM @TblGroup g
    LEFT JOIN @TblAmount a ON g.Grp_Id = a.Grp_Id
    WHERE GrpType = 'Expence') as Expence on  Income.Income<>Expence.Expence
```

Where duplicate Income and Expense is coming in an output, How could I overcome this Issue.

Comment: All you really need here is a simple join, but the exact output you showed us is really best handled in your presentation layer, not SSMS.

Comment: Is `Grp_Id` unique in both tables? If so, why do you have two tables and not just one?

Comment: What makes you decide to show 'Direct Incomes' with 'Misc. Expenses'? Why not 'Purchases' for instance? I don't see any relation and so Tim is right: do this in your app, maybe even using two grids/tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the Answer, Here is the solution.

```
        declare @TblGroup as table (Grp_Id int, Grp_Name varchar(50), GrpType varchar(20))
insert into @TblGroup values    
     (1,'Direct Incomes','Income')
    ,(2,'Indirect Incomes','Income')
    ,(3,'Misc. Expences','Expence')
    ,(4,'Other Incomes','Income')
    ,(5,'Purchases','Expence')
    ,(6,'Selling Expences','Expence')
    ,(7,'Sales','Income')

declare @TblAmount as table(Grp_Id int,Amount int)
insert into @TblAmount values
     (1,2000)   
    ,(2,1500)   
    ,(3,3000)   
    ,(4,5000)   
    ,(5,4000)   
    ,(6,1000)   
    ,(7,4500)   

        SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as SNo, TG.Grp_Name AS Income, TA.Amount  into #Incme
        FROM @TblGroup TG, @TblAmount TA 
        WHERE TA.Grp_Id = TG.Grp_Id 
          AND TG.GrpType = 'Income';

        SELECT  Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as SNo , TG.Grp_Name AS Expence, TA.Amount  into #Expnse
        FROM @TblGroup TG, @TblAmount TA 
        WHERE TA.Grp_Id = TG.Grp_Id 
          AND TG.GrpType = 'Expence';

    DECLARE @TblMain as table(Income varchar(50), Amount int, Expense varchar(50), Amount2 int)
    DECLARE  @row INT = 1
            ,@ROWCOUNT int 
            ,@RowCount_Incme INT = (select COUNT(*) from #Incme)
            ,@RowCount_Expnse INT = (select COUNT(*) from #Expnse)

        set @ROWCOUNT = case when @RowCount_Incme > @RowCount_Expnse then @RowCount_Incme else @RowCount_Expnse end

    WHILE (@ROW <= @ROWCOUNT)
    BEGIN
            insert into @TblMain(Income, Amount,Expense,Amount2) (
                select Income, Amount
                            ,(select Expence from #Expnse where SNo=@row) 
                            ,(select Amount from #Expnse where SNo=@row) 
                            from #Incme where SNo=@row
                )
        SET @ROW = @ROW+1
    END
    select * from @TblMain

    drop table #Incme
    drop table #Expnse
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple Left Join question, here's half of the solution

```
SELECT GrpType AS Income, TblAmount.Amount AS Amount
FROM TblGroup
LEFT JOIN TblAmount
ON TblGroup.Grp_Id = TblAmount.Grp_Id
WHERE GrpType = "Income"
```

You should be able to guess how to get the other result.

Comment: Do you know the other half?  I don't, because I don't know what view technology the OP is using.

Comment: Just simply replace Income with Expense? >.>

Comment: I think it's better to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` because as you said result can be selected for `income & expense` from separate set of query.

Comment: There is no change for output when I use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

Comment: It was just for performance point of view and the proper usage of join........sorry for not mentioning in.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT TG.Grp_Name AS Income, TA.Amount 
> FROM TblGroup TG, TblAmount TA 
> WHERE TA.Grp_Id = TG.Grp_Id 
>   AND TG.GrpType = 'Income';
>
> SELECT TG.Grp_Name AS Expence, TA.Amount 
> FROM TblGroup TG, TblAmount TA 
> WHERE TA.Grp_Id = TG.Grp_Id 
>   AND TG.GrpType = 'Expence';
> ```
>
> First query will give you the details for grpType income and the second gives the details for grpType expense.
>   A simple statement in the where clause can give you the output. You can also try it with SQL joins. But I prefer to go easy.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I did the above Query, But ot getting the exact result here , Where the answer with duplicate Income and Expense.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TblGroup ( Grp_Id int, Grp_Name varchar(200),
                                             GrpType varchar(200));


INSERT INTO TblGroup
VALUES(1,
       'Direct Incomes',
       'Income');


INSERT INTO TblGroup
VALUES(2,
       'Indirect Incomes',
       'Income');


INSERT INTO TblGroup
VALUES(3,
       'Misc. Expences',
       'Expence');


INSERT INTO TblGroup
VALUES(4,
       'Other Incomes',
       'Income');


INSERT INTO TblGroup
VALUES(5,
       'Purchases',
       'Expence');


INSERT INTO TblGroup
VALUES(6,
       'Selling Expences',
       'Expence');


INSERT INTO TblGroup
VALUES(7,
       'Sales',
       'Income');


CREATE TABLE TblAmount ( Grp_Id int, amount int);


INSERT INTO TblAmount
VALUES(1,
       2000);


INSERT INTO TblAmount
VALUES(2,
       1500);


INSERT INTO TblAmount
VALUES(3,
       3000);


INSERT INTO TblAmount
VALUES(4,
       5000);


INSERT INTO TblAmount
VALUES(5,
       4000);


INSERT INTO TblAmount
VALUES(6,
       1000);


INSERT INTO TblAmount
VALUES(7,
       4500);


SELECT DISTINCT Income,
                c.amount,
                Expence,
                d.amount from
  (SELECT a.Grp_Id, CASE
                        WHEN GrpType='Income' THEN Grp_Name
                    END AS Income, b.amount
   FROM TblGroup a
   INNER  JOIN TblAmount b ON a.Grp_Id=b.Grp_Id)c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT a.Grp_Id,
          CASE
              WHEN GrpType='Expence' THEN Grp_Name
          END AS Expence,
          amount
   FROM TblGroup a
   INNER  JOIN TblAmount b ON a.Grp_Id=b.Grp_Id)d ON c.Grp_Id=d.Grp_Id;
```

Comment: Not getting properly, Where if GrpType="Expence" then the Income side getting a null value.I don't need null value here.